# App get crash on animation of 2d objects in Unity 4.3

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, 2d

Getting bit issue on playing animation when first object collide to second object its OnCollisionEnter2D method I am playing animation. I attached animation with second object and when I run code it gets crash. Here is what I am doing. declare string on top and call on collision.

```
string blastAnim = "BlastAnim";

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){ Debug.Log("Collision Enter............."); animation.Play(blastAnim);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use 3d animation methods in 2d. There are different way to implement 2d animations in unity.

you need to create animation controller for sprite.
Create animation clip for the same.
Declare variable for Animator as

```
Animator anim;
void Start()
{
    anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    Animator anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    anim.SetBool("Jump",isJump);
}
```